# SubSonic and Azure Compatibility

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, azure

I have an application that's due to be rolled out in May. I just took over the project and dumped EntityFramework 1.0 in favor of SubSonic. (We don't have the time to wait for EF 4.0.)

There is the possibility of moving the application to Azure, and I was wondering what the implications of that might be. My understanding is that EF 4.0 is set up to work with Azure, but does EF 1.0 have anything to offer regarding connection to Azure that SubSonic does not?

Answer (score 1):

In regards to connection to Sql Azure, I think they both are the same.  I just got the SubSonic ActiveRecord MVC sample up and running on Azure and SqlAzure.  The only strange thing I notice is there is a guid instead of a user name for the blog entry author (System.Environment.UserName).

If you want to try out their sample you'll want the SqlAzure membership scripts, which you can get here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB2006191

Other than the UserName strangeness, all the other database access seems to be what I would expect.

Are you thinking of using the ActiveRecord or SimpleRepository?

**EDIT**

After changing the t4 ActiveRecord template output the following instead of just the Environment.UserName, the blog sample works the same as is does outside of the cloud:

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
{
    this.ModifiedBy=System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
}
else
{
    this.ModifiedBy = Environment.UserName;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.

You just solved two problems for me. I was having trouble with Environment.UserName too.   :)

We're releasing a fairly complex (57 tables) Microsoft MVC application using ActiveRecord. We're a diverse group, and ActiveRecord let's everyone do their own thing, their way.

Happy programmers write happy software...    :)